# Under what conditions do Ender Pearls despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use long-term Ender Pearl stasis on a server that I frequent as a sort of fast travel. A chamber has been failing on me lately, leading to a rather lengthy trek each time.

This leads to the question. Under *what precise conditions* will an ender pearl disappear without teleporting the thrower? The player being offline is an obvious one - are there any others?

Comment: Is the server you play on completely vanilla or does it have any form of plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pearl despawns on owner's death (unless the gamerule doImmediateRespawns is set to true) or if it's triggered (collides with a solid surface), regardless of whether the owner can be teleported or not: in particular, the owner may be in other dimension (no cross-dimension teleportation allowed), logged out or dead.

Comment: In old versions of Minecraft, a triggered Ender Pearl could still teleport a player to its coordinates just leaving the player in that dimension. I don't know if this still works.

Comment: @pinckerman It doesn't - and it was definitely a bug.

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: Death. That must be it - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A EnderPearl will also despawn if you thow it into the void